# Is there a way to run qmake with QT 5.7 and above?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a project I made with Qt 5.7 in QtCreator, but now I would like to be able to build the project with qmake in the terminal rather than through QtCreator. However, I can't get qmake to run with Qt 5.7.

Following the instructions in [this webpage](https://harishnavnit.wordpress.com/2014/03/24/handling-multiple-versions-of-qt/), I can switch qmake to qt5 but qmake -v still says I'm running QT 5.2.1. How can I switch this to Qt 5.7?

Edit: Adrien's second comment worked. I was unable to get qmake to switch to Qt 5.7, but I can simply directly call the qmake that came installed with Qt 5.7 like this:

```
/home/<user>/Qt5.7/Qt5.7.0/gcc<something>/bin/qmake
```

Comment: You must install a version greater than or equal to 5.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: yes of course :)

Each Qt build builds its own `qmake` binary. So if you already built/installed Qt 5.7, it means you are simply pointing to your previous Qt version's qmake. You can access any Qt version `qmake` executable from your Qt install folder, i.e. for Linux:

```
/home/<user_name>/Qt/Qt<version>/<compiler>/bin/qmake
```

Note that the path to `Qt`folder, and its name may vary depending on the settings you used for the first installation.

---

If you want to use a global setting instead, and if `qtchooser -list-versions` lists the Qt version you want to use, then make sure to set `export QT_SELECT=<Qt version>` (without spaces) in the same terminal as the one you use `qmake` from afterward. Environment variables are not kept when you close your terminal, or shared between different terminals.

```
export QT_SELECT=qt5
qmake
```

Comment: Sorry for not being more clear. I did attempt to set  export QT_SELECT = qt5, however this only sets qmake to run with qt 5.2.1. When I use qtchooser to see the list of qmake versions, with qtchooser - l, there's no option for qt 5.7, just qt5. I do have qt 5.7 installed, I'm just not sure how to change qmake to use qt 5.7, since qmake 5.7 doesn't show up when I run qtchooser - l to see the list of available qt versions.

Comment: Ok, depending how you installed Qt 5.7, that's likely that it was not automatically detected. I would then simply recommand directly calling the qmake of Qt 5.7. If you installed it in your home folder for instance (default for Qt installer), you can directly use it from `/home/<user>/Qt/5.7/gcc<something>/bin/qmake`